# css: text-align: center only working on multiline text, not single line?

Tags: html, css

The problem is as shown in the link below - The text overlaying the images only centers correctly when it's multiple lines... The problem persists when scaling the window.

[This is the problem](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11434436/Capture.JPG)

The html:

```
<body>
    <div id="navbar">
        ...
    </div> 
    <div class="picFrame" id="pf1"></div>
    <div class="picFrame" id="pf2"></div>
    <div class="picFrame" id="pf3"></div>
</body>
```

I'm adding the pictures with js, by appending to each picFrame in turn.
the js:

```
$("#pf1").append('<div class="cont"><img src="pics/' + a[i][0] + '"><span>' + a[i][1] + ' - ' + a[i][2] + '</span></div>');
```

The relevant css:

```
span {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    bottom: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 5px;
}
.cont {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.picFrame {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32%;
}
img {
    margin: 0 0 4% 0;
    border-radius: 4%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

So the question is - why doesn't single line text center, and how do I fix this?

Thank you in advance,
J.

Comment: Provide a fiddle code with your issue.

Comment: Not sure how that is going to help, when fiddle doesn't have acces to the picures, but here it is:
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/8nqrY/)

Comment: You can add the image external path in the fiddle. Or you can provide a link where it is located.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without a working example to go on, it might work to add this:

```
span {width: 100%}
```

That worked in the code that I reconstructed, but it might not relate to your actual situation.